# XML into browser using GET HTTP request

Tags: ajax

Could someone give an exmaple of simple code which will retrieve xml data into a browser from an API which is available on a different server via GET HTTP.

I am struggling to get around cross origin issues using XmlHttpRequest. But I am unsure whether I should try to get around these issues or if there is an alternative solution.

The code will reside locally (on my PC)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","my url",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<p>Click the button several times to see if the time changes, or if the file is cached.</p>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please post the code that you have been trying?

Comment: Here is example:http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp